# What is a message in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

What does the term 'message' mean in the context of Objective-C?

Answer (score 11):

[Messages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages) in Objective-C are akin to [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_%28computer_programming%29) calls in C++.

In Objective-C, you don't *call a method*, you *send a message*.

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, sorry! The class behaviours are still known as methods, however you don't **call** them you send them a **message**.

Comment: @Slomojo, no problem, terminology is important in this case. Answer updated, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: @Slomojo: If you want to be pedantic, go all the way.  :)  You send a message to the *object*.  The object, or the runtime, then decides what method to use to handle the message.  It's possible to somewhat decouple the message from the calling of a method (that is, make it so method name != message name), and languages like Smalltalk, Ruby, and even PHP can do it.  C++, Java, etc...not so much.  Not sure yet if Objective-C can, but evidence of the ability would be an overridable method akin to Smalltalk's `doesNotUnderstand:`, Ruby's `method_missing`, or PHP's `__call`.

Comment: @cHao ... careful now, objects created by classes are called, in idiomatic language `instances`, so we'd be messaging an `instance method` or a `class method` context dictating which. - Of course, the language is slightly muddy within the Apple Docs, `instance variables` are usually the only way `properties`/`members` are referred to, but `object method` / `instance method` get equal traction... ultimately, we all knew a year ago what we were saying, but thanks for dropping by.

Answer (score 3):

If you're at that level of understanding/bemusement, then I'd recommend a read of Apple's excellent "[Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)", as you really need to understand some of the basics before you get any further.

In essence, a message is effectively a method call in Objective-C. (Instead of passing arguments to a method, you "send a message".)